# SharePoint DLL'S missing in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, infopath

- Dear All,   I have no SharePoint installed in my PC except visual
  studio and designer 2013.
- But want to program for Infopath and get the requirement done.I had installed
  .MSI file from the below url and I see no dll's installed in ISAPI folder except the below existing dll's from image.
- Can any one help me where does the dll's should have got installed

https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=35585

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you installed is SharePoint client components SDK, in order to write any managed code for InfoPath you need to install visual studio tools for applications VSTA.